# How to sort a huge arrayList<JSONObject>(about 2000 records)?

Tags: java, android, json

How to sort a huge `arrayList<JSONObject>`(about 2000 records) in android by specific property in each object

i used collection sort but it takes too much time for loading data and I can't save data in ROOM(`SQLite` database) because it's a dynamic app with different types of data.
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: sorting large collection will take time, question is what are you doing with data? can you for example find N lowest and N highest entries and present them to user and sort data in background while he is looking at that set? is it possible to get data sorted by whoever provides it?

Comment: i sorted data by collection.sort in background but i didn't test it by showing high/lower data, its sort by bubble method
@user902383

Comment: this is my method
`Collections.sort(name, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public int compare(JSONObject jsonObject, JSONObject t1) {
 String one = null, two = null;
 try {
 one = jsonObject.get(sort.get(0)).toString();
two = t1.get(sort.get(0)).toString();
 } catch (JSONException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 return one.compareTo(two);
}
}); `

Comment: Let's start from beginning, what you want to do with sorted data? Do you want to display it to user process somehow or what?

Comment: yes i display it by recyclerView @user902383